# How to gain access to the akka system created via guice?

Tags: scala, playframework, guice, playframework-2.4

So I'm following the template here:
https://github.com/rocketraman/activator-akka-scala-guice#master

I've ported this code over to a version 2.4 Play app.

Now I am able to create the actor system and create the actors inside the Global class and send the initial messages to the actors. I've also set up routes to try to talk to certain actors and get status but I am unable to since I cannot access that original actor system.

How can I accomplish this? I think in the older Play versions, we have getControllerInstance; which is used in the following:

```
  /**
   * Controllers must be resolved through the application context. There is a special method of GlobalSettings
   * that we can override to resolve a given controller. This resolution is required by the Play router.
   */
  override def getControllerInstance[A](controllerClass: Class[A]): A = injector.getInstance(controllerClass)
```

From that, we can inject certain dependencies in the controller. Now that this is removed, we can no longer do that. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Why do you want to create a new Akka system? Play incorporates one already and you can access it via `Akka.system()`.

Answer (score 3):

[It's pretty clear how to inject Akka system in to the controller](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.2/ScalaAkka)

```
import play.api.mvc._
import akka.actor._
import javax.inject._

import actors.HelloActor

@Singleton
class Application @Inject() (system: ActorSystem) extends Controller {

  val helloActor = system.actorOf(HelloActor.props, "hello-actor")

  //...
}
```

take in to attention *@Singleton* here is only to store reference to the actor - not the ActorSystem, [it's handled by the Play in backend](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.2/ScalaAkka)

> A Play application defines a special actor system to be used by the
>   application. This actor system follows the application life-cycle and
>   restarts automatically when the application restarts.